# branch already up to date git despite problem in merge

Tags: git

I merged the dev branch into my own branch but it had some conflicts and when I resolved them I couldn't merge it directly due to some husky error then I commit the changes by myself but I accidentally missed some changes and rollback them.
and when I want to merge dev into my It shows already uptodate
please help me

Answer (score 0):

When you commit a merge, you tell Git that what you have committed is the correct *result* of the merge.  Git believes you!  From then on, that *is* the correct result of the merge.

If you did the merge wrong and want to throw away *all* of your work and start over, tell Git to eject the merge commit off the end of the branch:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

for instance.  (Be **very** careful with `git reset`; it's a powerful and destructive tool, especially when used with `--hard`.)

The merge you made is not actually *gone* at this point, but you can't see it any more, and Git no longer has that merge on your branch.  You can now run `git merge dev` again to start over.

If you *do* want to keep *some* of the results of the merge you made, but don't want to keep the whole merge, make a *temporary branch or tag name* **before** you run `git reset --hard`, e.g.:

```
git branch save-temporarily
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Now you can use `git restore` to extract specific files from the `save-temporarily` commit:

```
git merge dev
[Git's merge messages spew out here]

# file path/to/file.py, I merged properly last time, so:
git restore --source=save-temporarily -W path/to/file.py
```

for instance.

(Use a shorter name than `save-temporarily`, but still something that will remind you what this is about, so that you don't have to type as much in.)

When you are done re-doing the merge, you can delete the temporary branch or tag name.  (The example here uses a branch name, but for this particular purpose, either branch *or* tag is just as good, and there's no particular reason to prefer one or the other.)